# PGSQL: Selecting values from first table and inserting them as one of the params to the second table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Is is possible to do something like this or similar in PostgreSQL?

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (some_varchar_value, id_value_table_1)
VALUES ('some_varchar_value', SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table_1)
```

In short I want to select ids from table_1 and insert them as a second param of insert to table_2. The first of inserted values will be a const of varchar type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (some_varchar_value, id_value_table_1)
SELECT DISTINCT 'some_varchar_value', id
FROM table_1;
```